# Replace several lines

Tags: replace, newline, notepad++, findinfiles

In Notepad++, I would like to (find-in-files and) replace several lines, but I fail to paste several lines into the "Replace what:" text-box.

I select the lines in an opened file, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, and I get the lines copied into the "Find what:" text-box. "Extended" is pre-selected.

The problem is, when I try to copy the lines from the "Find what:" text-box to the "Replace with:" text-box, *only the first line is copied*. Had the lines appeared with `\r\n` it would have solved the problem, but they don't. (I did get once the lines to appear in "Find what:" with the `\r\n`, but I don't know what caused it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cumbersome workaround:

- open a file with the multiple-lines you want to copy (but can't) into the find/replace box.
- replace (using "Extended") all `\r\n` into `\\r\\n`.
- you can now copy the multiple-lines as one line (with the new `\r\n` as text) to the search-box.

Answer (score 0):

The **Find what** and **Replace** fields take a single line each. Those lines can match or generate, respectively, multiple lines by inserting the four characters `\r\n` where line breaks are needed; provided the **Extended** or **Regular expression** are selected.

To generate four lines of text the **Replace** field could be set to contain these 31 characters `One\r\nTwo\r\nThree\r\nFour\r\n`

---

Notepad has three search modes to control how the characters within the **Find what** and **Replace** fields are interpreted. See the *Searching ... Normal search* part of the Notepad++ help pages for more details.

**Normal** means 
is handled literally. That means a **Find what** string such as `s\t` looks for the three letters `s`, `\` and `t` in that order.

**Extended** means that `\` characters are used to indicate special characters such as newline and tab characters, etc. That means a **Find what** string such as `s\t` looks for the two letters `s` and TAB in that order. To look for the three letters `s`, `\` and `t` in that order needs the **Find what** string to be `s\\t`.

**Regular Expression** means that several other characters are interpreted, not as themselves but, specially as parts of a regular expression.

Comment: Extended is pre-selectred. I don't understand your suggestion.